# How to use a BLDC motor, solar panels and batteries efficiently

Tags: solar-cell, brushless-dc-motor, series, lead-acid

I have a 48V 1800W BLDC motor, 4X 12V lead acid batteries and 4X 100W 12V solar panel.

My question is, can we use those 4 lead acid batteries when connected in series to power the BLDC motor?

If the answer is yes to that question, can we use the above mentioned solar panels to charge the batteries? If yes how much time will it take to charge them at peak hours?

If the above mentioned parts are not compatible with each other, what would you guys recommend to use in terms of motor, batteries and solar panels so that I would get high power yield and also to charge the batteries with solar panels in as less time as possible. The budget for my project is $800 USD. Need help with these things.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  You'll find you get the best from EE.SE if you give as much information as you have.  For this kind of problem, you really have to think about the capacity of the batteries and the charge/run ratio required.  What is it for?  Is it an exercise for a course?

Comment: How much insolation will there be in *peak hours*, how clean and new will the panels be? Depending on circumstances, "mirrors" directing (additional) light to the panels and "solar trackers" are more effective than MPP trackers.

Comment: 1800W motor powered by 400W of panels. How long are you hoping to run the motor for?

Comment: @Finbarr, I did not get you when you said 400W of panels for 1800W motor. Are you’d saying that 4 of those panels will be sufficient? I’m planning to run the motor until it reaches the peak of the 4 12V 9ah lead acid batteries. Not expecting a lot. But how much ever time it can be run.